# Emoji does not display in push Notification

Tags: ios, unicode, push-notification, emoji

I implement the functionality of push Notification in my app. This display text message in push notification but emoji not display. It display ascii code like '\u270c' instead of emoji.

can anyone tell me how to display emoji in push notification

Comment: try with [emojis with unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display Emoji in Push Notification use JSON Decoding at server side. It solves this issue for me
Do this at server side in APNS push notification code and will work like charm

```
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => json_decode('"'.$pushMsg['message'].'"'), 'badge' => 0, 'sound' => 'default', 'passcode' => $pushMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your unicode format to display emoji in push notification and local notification.

Update your unicode as follows:

```
"\u{270c}"
```

I hope this will help you.

Reference: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: where should i change unicode in application side or server side?

Comment: It is better if you change its server side.

Comment: If you changing it from server side then you need to change it manually in your emojis unicode list.

Comment: If you want to change it to application side then need to use notification service extension where you can change body of notification extension. need to check there is unicode available in body then change it to required format. But this is not proper solution as like server side change.